# Getting error "The owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist " in DXVA2 but not in DXVAHD while calling ConnectDirect() MSFT API.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, directshow, directshow.net

I am getting the error "The owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist " in the return value "hr" when I call:

```
hr = pGraph->ConnectDirect(pOut, pIn, NULL);
```

I get this error only when I use DXVA2 but it returns S_OK when DXVAHD is used.

Can anyone kindly let me know the reaosn for this.

I suspect the the 3rd argument that I have given for "ConnectDirect()" i.e Media Type is NULL. I must have given some other type is it?

The pOut & pIn for the 2 filter are correct as I could observe from the S_OK return value while getting the pin values.

Since ConnectDirect() is a Microsoft API, I am not able to step into the code tooi order to do furtehr debug.

Can anyone kindly help me in getting this fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is `0x80040207` "There is no common media type between these pins.", `VFW_E_NO_ACCEPTABLE_TYPES`. There is something in your graph building done incorrectly.

Comment: But I wonder how come the SAME code doesnt give any error for DXVAHD ? This error is ONLY for DXVA2. ? It would be helpful if u stress on this point?

Comment: This is a "standard" error. You attempt to connect pins directly - pins failed to connect. Without going into details (which you need to provide to go into), the error indicates that no such connection is possible. Try to `Connect` instead of `ConnectDirect` to see if any intermediate filters are taken. Check what filters and pins are being connected, media types involved. You have not given these details so far.